# Lazarus/Free Pascal: read/write nodes with the same name using TXMLConfig

Tags: xml, lazarus, freepascal

It seems like `TXMLConfig` is only good for basic and simple saving of properties/settings for your application and not fit for full-on XML file parsing. You're supposed to only read XML files, which have also been created by your application. Under these circumstances, it makes sense that there is no support for nodes with the same name, since it would represent the same property/setting.

Let's assume the following XML file:

```
<Configuration Version="1.0">
  <Family Name="Simpson">
    <Member Gender="Male">Homer</Member>
    <Member Gender="Female">Marge</Member>
    <Member Gender="Male">Bart</Member>
    <Member Gender="Female">Lisa</Member>
    <Member Gender="Female">Maggie</Member>
  </Family>
</Configuration>
```

I read [this official tutorial](http://wiki.freepascal.org/xmlconf) and searched the web, but couldn't figure it out. Is there any way to use `TXMLConfig` to read Lisa's gender for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the TXMLConfig class since that does indeed only work if you do not have multiple nodes with the same name inside the same parent node.

You have to use the more low level functions. Here is an example how to lookup the gender of Lisa:

```
uses
  Classes, SysUtils, CustApp, Dom, XmlRead

var
  Doc: TXMLDocument;
  Members: TDOMNodeList;
  Member: TDOMNode;
  Gender: TDOMNode;
  i: integer;
begin

  // Read the XML file into an XML Document
  ReadXMLFile(Doc, 'D:\A.xml');

  // Get all nodes with name "Member"
  Members:= Doc.GetElementsByTagName('Member');

  // For all Member nodes
  for i:= 0 to Members.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Member:= Members[i];

    // Check if their content is Lisa
    if(Member.TextContent = 'Lisa') then
    begin
      // Get the attribute with name "Gender"
      Gender:= Member.Attributes.GetNamedItem('Gender');

      // Output the value of the attribute
      Writeln(Gender.TextContent);
    end;
  end;

  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: (It would be a good idea to have some support in TXMLConfig this. I ran into this in 2006, but luckily could around by using member1,member2 etc as tag types)

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort - I had the same problem last year and solved it the same way as you

Comment: I'm still using a hacked 2006 version of the laz_*xml* under Delphi. I plan to update it to the FPC (not Laz_*) versions somewhere in the hopefully near future. I'll see if I can then modernize/integrate it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Only to register more option.

```
procedure TFMain.getTicket;
var xDoc: TXMLDocument;
    xNode : TDOMNode;
begin

 tickt.Clear; // As TMemo

 xDoc  := DOMFromStream( rest );

 xNode := xDoc.ChildNodes.Item[ 0 ];

 tickt.Lines.Text := 'Id.....: ' + xNode.FindNode( 'id'      ).TextContent +#13
                   + 'Name...: ' + xNode.FindNode( 'name'    ).TextContent +#13
                   + 'e-mail.: ' + xNode.FindNode( 'email'   ).TextContent +#13
                   + 'Address: ' + xNode.FindNode( 'address' ).TextContent +#13
                   + 'City...: ' + xNode.FindNode( 'city'    ).TextContent +#13
                   + 'Phone..: ' + xNode.FindNode( 'phone1'  ).TextContent +#13
                   ;


end;
```